# Fertiliser analysis - Why doesn't it show ureic nitrogen when it does have urea?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I have had two types of urea fertiliser analysed, the results are as follows:

$\mathrm{46\%N}$ (46% nitrogen) - which is sold as a urea fertiliser, tests at 46.1% ureic nitrogen.

$\mathrm{38\%N~ 19\%S}$ (38% nitrogen, 19% sulphur) - which I understand to contain ammonium sulphate and urea, tests at 33% nitric nitrogen and 7.4% ammoniacal nitrogen

My question is-  why does the $\mathrm{38\%N~ 19\%S}$ show no ureic nitrogen when it is supposed to contain urea - the same as the $\mathrm{46\%N}$?

edit - the analysis company has admitted a mistake- the test  result should have read 33% ureic nitrogen and not 33% nitric nitrogen.

Comment: There is no question; the OP has withdrawn the initial data.